# how to change a rectangle values after drawing it?

Tags: c#

So I was making a flappy bird copy. But after drawing a rectangle I can't change it's values, when I change the 'pipe1.X' its gonna be changed but never actually changed in the Form. I want the 'rect' which is the bird to change it's Y position when the space button is clicked and when the timer1 executes the code 'rect.Y -= gravity;' so it constantly falls down. I wanted to make the pipes move to the left but for some reason none of the controls are moving. I tried debugging it with the breakpoints and the rec.Y was changing like I wanted but it doesn't change in the form.

```
    int pipeSpeed = 1;
    int gravity = 1;
    static int y = 150;
    static int xP = 640;
    static int yP1 = 0;
    static int yP2 = 260;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Random r = new Random();

    public int a;
    public int b;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //640, -27, 16, 150
        timer1.Interval = 500;
        a = r.Next(25, 150);
        b = r.Next(150, 300);
        timer1.Start();

    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(25, y, 25, 25);
    Rectangle pipe1 = new Rectangle(xP, yP1, 25, 0);
    Rectangle pipe2 = new Rectangle(xP, yP2, 25, 0);
    private void update()
    {

    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        pipe1.X -= pipeSpeed;
        rect.Y -= gravity;


        if (xP == -35)
        {
            pipe1 = new Rectangle(xP, yP1, 25, 0);
            pipe2 = new Rectangle(xP, yP2, 25, 0);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
        {
            rect.Y -= 5;

        }

    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Red),rect);
        pipe1.Height = a;
        pipe2.Height = b;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Black),pipe1);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Black), pipe2);

    }`
```

Comment: `FillRectangle` is drawing your rectangles, changing a value the of `pipes` will not affect the drawn rectangle, you will need to invalidate refresh the screen

Comment: inshort, invalidate your form after changing the rectangles

Comment: Ok but how do i fix it? @TheGeneral

Comment: @BugFinder worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
    {
        rect.Y -= 5;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

}
```

and

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     this.Invalidate();
}
```

[Form.Invalidate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control
>   to be redrawn.

Note there are more overloads and other tricks to make this more efficient, however this should at least let you redraw the form